# Disabling the global_step warning when using the MonitoredTrainingSession

Tags: python, tensorflow

In one of my Tensorflow programs, I used `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(checkpoint_dir='./logdir')` for training networks. While training, I need to check accuracy on **the validation set** from time to time. However, I observe that if opt.minimize or opt.apply_gradients is not called, which is expected for checking accuracy on the validation set, then it yields the following warnings:

**WARNING:tensorflow:It seems that global step (tf.train.get_global_step) has not been increased. Current value (could be stable): 3240 vs previous value: 3240. You could increase the global step by passing tf.train.get_global_step() to Optimizer.apply_gradients or Optimizer.minimize.**

To understand why it happens, I created the following simple a toy program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.get_variable('a', initializer=tf.constant([1.0]))
b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=tf.constant([2.0]))
c = a + b 

global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(checkpoint_dir='./logdir') as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  print (sess.run(c))

  for _ in range(100):
    sess.run(c)
```

The above program also shows the same kinds of warning:

**WARNING:tensorflow:It seems that global step (tf.train.get_global_step) has not been increased. Current value (could be stable): 0 vs previous value: 0. You could increase the global step by passing tf.train.get_global_step() to Optimizer.apply_gradients or Optimizer.minimize.**

But in some cases like checking accuracy on the development set, it is expected that the global_step is not increased. When calling sess.run, are there any ways to disable this warning?